# Build a new scheme fail because of cocoaPods cannot be found

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have an iOS project using CocoaPods. For some reasons,I must create a new configuration and accordingly a new scheme.Everything was working smoothly on the original config,but when it came to the new config,the result was like this:

[image]

Since I added this config by duplicating the original one, so the settings should be the same.Should I reset the file of cocoaPods,please kindly let me know,thanks.

Comment: try running pod install again

Comment: Julie you are great, thanks !